# Custom .XSN and Enterprise Licensing needed?

Tags: 2010, infopath, forms-services

if I develop a custom .XSN (InfoPath Form Template) can I store in SharePoint and provide a custom application page that leverages the XmlFormView to render out a browser enabled form WITHOUT the need for an Enterprise License?  This would be similar to the logic on some of the Workflow Forms, such as "_layouts/WrkTaskIP.aspx"

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Licensing is always tricky. On [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.infopath.server.controls.xmlformview.aspx) it says:

> InfoPath Forms Services uses the XmlFormView control to display forms
>   based on form templates designed in Microsoft InfoPath 2010 so that
>   they are browser-compatible. Developers can also use the XmlFormView
>   control to show InfoPath forms in custom Web pages. This requires
>   Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 with a client access license for
>   InfoPath Forms Services.

Should probably check this out with either someone who sells licenses or MS, what I always does when i'm in doubt.